# Old website still found on google but redirects to new site

Tags: seo, google-search, 301-redirect, 302-redirect

We have launched a new website replacing our old one, and Google now finds the new *and* the old website. Our old website was published under `/public`, the new one is published under `/web`:

Setup until July:

- `ourdomain.com -> 302 to ourdomain.com/public/index.html`

Setup from July (new website):

- `ourdomain.com -> 302 to ourdomain.com/web/de/index.html`
- `ourdomain.com/public/* -> 301 to ourdomain/web/de/index.html`

The problem is that the old website (next to the new one) still shows up. I've tried re-crawling the old website under `/public` in the Google Search Console, but that did not do the trick.

We want the old site to disappear from Google completely. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not ever do temporary redirects (302), but permanent redirects if you wish to replace an old URL/Domain with a new one.

Once the permanent redirects are in place (301) - preferably at webserver level, the old URLs will be replaced over time - give it up to 2 weeks - that's the average. It depends on how often your site is crawled. Then again don't worry as if a visitor clicks the old URL they will be redirected to the new one. 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en
https://seo-hacker.com/301-302-redirect-affect-seo/

If you wish to remove URLs manually - check out this - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en